# How to make website with google map available offline

Tags: html, offline-caching, kmz

I have created a webpage http://babysoftblog.co.cc/shahma/kmz/map_sexten.html in html5 with offline cache.its showing google map using a kmz file.the page is working fine online..but its not showing google map when page is o[en offline.
Am i doing any mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Maps can't be used offline like that. Google Maps is much more than just the initial Lib, for example images, location data etc. If your website doesn't require all the navigation feature, I recommend check out Static Map API.

Initially you include the static map, which is just image file that can be cached offline, then check for connectivity status and load the dynamic map later (aka Progressive Enhancement).